# Swift - Remote Notifications and Navigation Controller Flow

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification

I am setting up Push Notifications that I will send to the device with some data, and I want to load a certain view on the navigation controller stack.
However, I want to keep the navigation stack intact, i.e. the destination view controller should still have a navigation bar with back button to go backwards to previous view controller, etc.

Flow:
Navigation Controller -> Root View Controller -> Destination Controller.

How can I go about displaying a specific, non-root, view controller in a UINavigationController stack without losing hierarchy and functionality?

Right now I am doing this and it shows the View Controller properly, but no navigation bar:

```
        let idPushNotification = userInfo["idPushNotification"] as String
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationViewController") as DestinationViewController
        destinationViewController.idPushNotification = idPushNotification.toInt()!

        let navigationController = self.window?.destinationViewController;
        navigationController?.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It's because you are presenting view controller not pushing it try to call pushviewController instead of presentViewController

Comment: See the demo i have created will help you to understand https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7nf5fm9cicjy59/demoNavigation.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are presenting the view controller so it will not show any navigationBar.You need `pushViewController` on navigation stack

```
    let navigationController:UINavigationController = self.window?.destinationViewController as UINavigationController;
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)
```

Comment: Yup I tried that shortly after posting the question and that was the fix. Thanks!