# Swift didReceiveRemoteNotification - Navigate to rootviewcontroller no matter where in app user is located (Now With Error Message)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, apple-push-notifications, rootview

Upon receiving push notification in the IOS Swift app, I would like to do two things based on content in notification:

1. Either navigate to screen (deeplink) so i would have to navigate from rootviewcontroller through several screens.
2. Navigate to rootviewcontroller, no matter where the user is located in the app.

The second one I see as prerequisite for the first one.

I know that I need to place code in these two functions:

- didReceiveRemoteNotification
- didReceiveLocalNotification

**Error message: 'UIViewcontroller?' does not have a member named 'navigationController'**

In the file AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) 
{
    println("didReceiveRemoteNotification")
    //Navigate to rootviewcontroller
    var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CurrentShows")
        as ViewController

    //rootViewController.navigationController?
    //    .popToViewController(setViewController, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Please clarify as to what is not happening, or where it crashes if it does so.

Comment: Updated with error message in bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code In your method :

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

var setViewController = mainStoryboard
    .instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CurrentShows")
        as ViewController_CurrentShows

rootViewController
    .navigationController
    .popToViewController(setViewController, animated: false)
```

Comment: Im running code from appDelegate.swift

Code doesn't seem to work. 
"UIViewController? does not have a member named navigationcontroller.

Where do I set the viewControllerIidentifier?
I imagine that it is the viewcontroller which i wanna navigate to which should be placed here right?

Comment: Yes..select the viewcontroller and in identity inspecter window set storyboard id there.

Comment: It makes the app crash.

Comment: Hmm. Dificult to show you a log as it is in production. Can't test push notificaations in test environment. Or I don't know how.

Comment: Just asking: Have you pushed the viewController you are popping here? ;-) Could it be you have a similar problem as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27415961/1548472)?

Comment: If i put this code in a viewcontroller it still doesnt work, though i have another error message:
"Viewcontroller" does not have amember named 'window'

Answer (score 0):

Needed to create a variable:
var window: UIWindow

Code below was implemented in appdelegate, in:
func didBecomeActive()....

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login") as Login_ViewController

            self.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:
            {
                if self.window != nil
                {
                    self.window!.rootViewController = rootController
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple class to navigate to any view controller in the view hierarchy from anywhere in one line of code by just passing the class type, so the code you'll write will be also decoupled from the view hierarchy itself, for instance:

```
Navigator.find(MyViewController.self)?.doSomethingSync()
Navigator.navigate(to: MyViewController.self)?.doSomethingSync()
```

..or you can execute methods asynchronously on the main thread also:

```
Navigator.navigate(to: MyViewController.self) { (MyViewControllerContainer, MyViewControllerInstance) in
    MyViewControllerInstance?.doSomethingAsync()
}
```

Here the GitHub project link: https://github.com/oblq/Navigator